How to get lastSignInDateTime from Azure AD through Postman
I need to fetch lastSignInDateTime from Azure AD through Postman.
May I know how I can the fetch the details of the users
I tried with below URL but it's not working for me.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,signInActivity.
Actually I need to fetch this detail from Azure AD to Saviynt.
you can see the JSON I use in below.
{
    "globalSettings": {
        "dateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    },
    "accountParams": {
        "connection": "userAuth",
        "processingType": "SequentialAndIterative",
        "call": {
            "call1": {
                "callOrder": 0,
                "stageNumber": 0,
                "http": {
                    "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,signInActivity",
                    "httpHeaders": {
                        "Authorization": "${access_token}",
                        "Accept": "application/json"
                    },
                    "httpContentType": "application/json",
                    "httpMethod": "GET"
                },
                "listField": "value",
                "keyField": "accountID",
                "colsToPropsMap": {
                    "accountID": "id~#~char",
                    "customproperty60": "signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime~#~char",
                    "lastlogondate": "signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime~#~date"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "entitlementParams": {},
    "acctEntParams": {}
}


Are you getting an error message?  If yes, can you please post it?

You need to grant AuditLog.Read.All permission to be able to read signInActivity. Without the permission, the signInActivity will be null

Currently the root cause of your error is unclear. So, if you send the request to graph, do you get a valid response? If no, what is the error? If yes, what do you expect to happen in Postman and what do you get instead?

@cdub i just checks logs what  can see error as : responseError : Authentication_MSGraphPermissionMissing .

@user2250152 apart from API permission whether we needs to add bete in URL. If yes or no why we needs to add to URL because i seen some others forums they are using :https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity

I agree with @user2250152, to fetch the signInActivity of the users the Microsoft Entra ID application must have AuditLog.Read.All API permission:
Grant the API permissions like below:

Generated access token by using below parameters via Postman:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials


By using the above access token, I am able to fetch the signInActivity of the users successfully:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,signInActivity



apart from permission issue whether we needs to use beta in URL?

AFAIK no. You can use v1.0 URL

Use this as URL in your ImportAccountEntJSON -
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,signInActivity

